# Why does Combine assign crash when writing to an optional property?

Tags: swift, combine

This code crashes ("Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value")

```
import Combine

class Receiver {
    var value: Int!
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>([])
    
    init(_ p: AnyPublisher<Int,Never>) {
        p.assign(to: \.value, on: self).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

let receiver = Receiver(Just(5).eraseToAnyPublisher())
```

It does not crash if I use `p.sink { self.value = $0 }.store(in: &cancellables)` instead of the assign, and it does not crash if I do not use an optional for the `value`-property.

To me this looks like a bug in Swift's constructor code, but maybe I am overlooking something?

Comment: in the assign `\.value` it is reading the value property, and because it's nil - exception

Comment: But I guess it shouldn't be like that, since it just overrides the changes. But currently it does read the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a bug in Combine, it’s accessing the value when assigning it. If you change it to be a regular Optional rather than an implicitly unwrapped one (change `!` to `?`) it’ll work fine. For the most part, you should avoid implicitly unwrapped Optionals except if they’re absolutely necessary for design constraints.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

`value` is an "Implicitly Unwrapped Optional" (and hence is an `Optional`), yet your `AnyPublisher`'s `Output` is `Int` - which is **not** an `Optional`.

### Solution

Change `AnyPublisher`'s `Output` from `Int`, to `Int?`, so that it will be an `Optional` as well. Here's your code example with this fix applied:

```
import Combine

class Receiver {
    var value: Int!
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>([])
    
    init(_ p: AnyPublisher<Int?, Never>) { // `Output` was changed from `Int` to `Int?` here.
        p.assign(to: \.value, on: self).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

let receiver = Receiver(Just(5).eraseToAnyPublisher())
```

Comment: @charles-maria I tried changing `value` from `Int!` to `Int?`, but that resulted in the following error: `error: key path value type 'Int?' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Int'`. But my code example above, in which I left `value` as `Int!` but changed `AnyPublisher<Int, Never>` to `AnyPublisher<Int?, Never>` worked without any problems for me :).